# Temporary activated border color for hamburger icon bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

When I click on the hamburger icon for a Bootstrap 4 page, the icon shows a colored border as it is activated, but then it goes away.  How can I change this color or even do away with it?  Here is sn unlisted youtube video that shows what I mean live in action.. http://youtu.be/kiiYmNM4OIo?hd=1

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

That would be the `outline` property.

To remove it, set it to `none`. It is normally applied at the `button:focus` event.

So

```
button:focus{outline:none;} /*completely remove the outline*/
```

or

```
button:focus{outline:5px dotted black;} /*example on how to set it to something else*/
```